# Designing the Entity Framework Structure for Image Tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm working with three tables: Movie, Actor, and Director, and I need to create additional tables to store images.

The core idea is to be able to add photos, associate them with movies, and specify the actors or directors depicted in the photos (with these associations being optional or it can be only associated with actor or director). This means that in the database schema, i will have one record in the 'Photo' table and multiple connections in the 'PhotoConnection' table.

Here's a breakdown of the tables:

Photo Table:

- ID
- Title
- Description
- URL

PhotoConnection Table:

- ID
- PhotoId
- Type
- ObjectId

In the 'PhotoConnection' table, the 'Type' field is an enumeration that indicates whether the connection is related to a Movie, Actor, or Director. The 'ObjectId' field stores the ID of the respective entity in one of these tables.

The primary challenge lies in implementing this schema using Entity Framework to enable easy searching of these tables. How can I best achieve this?

Comment: Generally storing images, or files for that matter, in the database is a less than ideal solution. Instead store the file in a directory and store the *path* to the file in the database.

Comment: Does not like he is storing images in the database his Photo table consist of an "URL"

Comment: Lets start with the db model. How do you think to maintain validity of the ObjectId that its actually points to an existing entry in one of the tables? To maintain integrity you typically would use 3 tables to get the foreign keys on those tables correct.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on your question. The ObjectId would correspond to the ID in one of my tables: Movie, Actor, or Director, depending on the 'Type' field.

Comment: I don't want to separate photos to 3 tables like PhotoMovies, PhotoDirectors, PhotoActors. I want to store it in one table to have easly access ane queries after.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to configure your tables is:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }            
    public IList<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
    public IList<Director> Directors { get; set; }
    public IList<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}

public class  Actor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public IList<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}

public class Director
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public IList<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}

public class Photo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    [DeleteBehavior(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)]
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public IList<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
    public IList<Director> Directors { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously, to handle all the (many to many) relationships, EF will create some additional tables, but don't worry about them, and use LINQ queries on these four tables as you prefer...